# how to display image in ios push notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10, unnotificationserviceextension

iOS 10 introduced push notification framework updates,

> UserNotificationsUI.framework

As written on apple docs, it lets us customize the appearance of local and remote notifications when they appear on the user’s device.

So if anyone have idea how to display image in push notification when on lock screen. same like andorid push notification are doing.

Thanks,

Comment: You can watch WWDC developer video. It is explaining at "Rich Notifications" lesson.

Comment: If someone needs: - I fond below blogpost and solved the problem: (Load image from url of remote notification) [http://www.avanderlee.com/ios-10/rich-notifications-ios-10/](http://www.avanderlee.com/ios-10/rich-notifications-ios-10/) And don't forget to add a line in your payload : "mutable_content": true,

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications

Comment: The top answer is MISLEADING. Why? Because the OP is asking about **remote** notifications. But the answer is mainly is showing how the image is attached and baked in from when the notification was created — **locally**. The only way to get a remote notification show its image is to have a `NotificationServiceExtension`. A `NotificationContentExtension` won't work because it's just to render existing content passed to it. The attachment has to be passed either locally or downloaded in the `NotificationServiceExtension`. For more on that see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/

Answer (score 91):

If you want to customize the appearance of local and remote notifications， perform the following steps：

1. Create a `UNNotificationCategory` and add to the `UNUserNotificationCenter` category:

   ```
   let newCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "newCategory",
                                            actions: [ action ],
                                            minimalActions: [ action ],
                                            intentIdentifiers: [],
                                            options: [])

   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

   center.setNotificationCategories([newCategory])
   ```
2. Create a UNNotificationContentExtension:

[image]

then use code or storyboard to customize your `UIViewController`.

3. Add category to `UNNotificationContentExtension`'s plist:

[image]

4.Push Notification

**Local Notification**

Create a `UNMutableNotificationContent` and set the `categoryIdentifier` to "newCategory" which includes `UNUserNotificationCenter`'s categories and `UNNotificationContentExtension`'s plist:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = ...
content.body = ...
content.categoryIdentifier = "newCategory"

let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "newNotificationRequest", content: content, trigger: nil)

let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.add(request)
```

**Remote Notification**

Set `"mutable-content : 1"` and `"category : newCategory"`. Note that the category value is set to "newCategory" which matches what you previously added to `UNUserNotificationCenter` and `UNNotificationContentExtension`s plist.

Example:

```
 {
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
        "title" : "title",
        "body" : "Your message Here"
        },
        "mutable-content" : "1",
        "category" : "newCategory"
    },
    "otherCustomURL" : "http://www.xxx.jpg"
 }
```

5. Note: you need a device or simulator which supports 3DTouch, otherwise you can't show a custom `UNNotificationContentExtension` viewcontroller.（In iOS10 Beta1, it`s not work. But now this work without 3d touch）

And ... if you just want to show an image on a push notification displayed on the lock screen, you need to add  `UNNotificationAttachment`:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = ...
content.body = ...
content.categoryIdentifier = "newCategory"

let fileURL: URL = ... //  your disk file url, support image, audio, movie

let attachement = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "attachment", url: fileURL, options: nil)
content.attachments = [attachement!]

let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "newNotificationRequest", content: content, trigger: nil)

let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.add(request)
```

[image]

For more detail feature,[Demo](https://github.com/maquannene/UserNotifications)

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. in point #5 you are saying none of this can be accomplished in a device that does not have 3d touch ?

Comment: @maquannene I'm pretty sure you have to set `"mutable-content": 1` ; i.e., `1` the integer, not `"1"` the string, or am I incorrect?

Comment: @JesusAdolfoRodriguez I write this answer in  iOS10 Beta1, and apple change it. This works without 3d touch when system greater than iOS10 Beta1.

Comment: what is the "attachement" in UNNotificationAttachment - identifier...? Im getting error in this line -(unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

Comment: @AbiramiBala: Have you solved that problem i also getting crash there

Comment: @maquannene : can you add a simple demo project for showing image in Remote Notification?

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal. yes, Solved, please go through this link, ask me, if you need i can share a sample code. Thanks...

Comment: @AbiramiBala : Sure share me the link

Comment: How to add Application extension in XCode-9?

Comment: @Alok File->New->Target. Then you have to find the Notification Content Extension or Notification Service Extension (depend on your needs).

Comment: @maquannene i tried several ways to implement Rich Push notification in Objective C but i cant find it from anywhere.can you please share any solution to implement this code in objective C

Comment: have i make certificate which make new notificationExtension and ServiceExtension ?

Comment: @maquannene Is it possible to send image via Firebase console?

Comment: how make certificate for service and content extension?..i implement using thses demo. but app is not running without certificate for service and content extension

Comment: i have set remote in urlSource in your demo code but app is crash

Comment: Demo project which you given is full of error,it will be much helpful if you provide error free github projects

Comment: This answer is MISLEADING. Why? Because the OP is asking about **remote** notifications. But the answer is mainly is showing how the image is attached and baked in from when the notification was created — **locally**. The only way to get a remote notification show its image is to have a `NotificationServiceExtension`. A `NotificationContentExtension` won't work because it's just to render existing content passed to it. The attachment has to be passed either locally or downloaded in the `NotificationServiceExtension`. For more on that see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/

Answer (score 13):

Actually if you are setting up a local notification and you're just interested in having an image show up in the notification itself, you don't have to bother with NotificationsUI.framework or UNNotificationContentExtensions at all. That is only useful if you want a custom UI when the user 3D touches or expands the notification.

To add an image that is already on the device (either shipped with the app, or generated/stored by the app at some point before the notification is created), then you only need to add a UNNotificationAttachment with a file URL where the path ends in .png (or .jpg will likely work too?). Something like this:

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
content.title = @"Title";
content.body = @"Body";
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:/some/path/in/app/image.png"];
NSError *error;
UNNotificationAttachment *icon = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:@"image" URL:imageURL options:nil error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"error while storing image attachment in notification: %@", error);
}
if (icon)
{
    content.attachments = @[icon];
}
```

Then when the notification appears, the image will show up on the right-hand side of the notification banner like it does for Messages notifications. And you don't have to jump through all of the hoops of setting up a content extension with a categoryIdentifier, etc.

EDIT: Updated to add that this is only a valid solution for local notifications.

Comment: Does this work for a remote file path, ie https://www.webservice/images/myimage.png?

Comment: Sorry, haven't tried, so I don't know if it does or not. Why not give it a try and see if it does or not?

Answer (score 5):

You have to do some work on creating push notification and also when you are handling.

1. When you creating payload you need to add extra attribute attachment, something like below:

   ```
   {        
       aps : {
           alert: { },
           mutable-content:1
       }
       my-attachment = "url to resource"
   }
   ```
2. When you receive notification system will call `didReceive` method of service extension, override notification extension `didReceive` method like this

   ```
   public func didReceive(_ request:UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler:(UNNotificatinContent) -> Void) {
       let fileUrl = //
       let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment(identifier : "image", url: fileUrl, options: nil)
       let content = request.content.mutableCopy as! UNMutableNotificationContent
       content.attachment = [attachment]
       contentHandler(content)
   }
   ```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/) is WWDC video talk on this topic.

Comment: mutable-content is the key that needs to be added to the aps dictionary.

Comment: You'll also need to download the the image

Answer (score 1):

With the version of Netmera SDK 3.14.4, you don't need to add a bridging header file to use iOS 10 media push. You should only implement the following methods in your Notification Service Extension to receive rich media push.
You can reach for both Swift and Objective-C.

**Step 1**

Remove the Objective-C Bridging Header file from the project and add:
`import NetmeraNotificationServiceExtension` in the NotificationService.swift file.

```
target 'your_service_extension_target_name' do

 pod "Netmera/NotificationServiceExtension"

end
```

After adding the previous line to your Podfile, `pod update` is used.

**Step 2**

Make sure you have Xcode 8 or a higher version installed. If not, upgrade your Xcode installation to use iOS10 media push on your application.
First you should create a new Notification Service Extension to your application. In order to do that, you should follow those steps:

- open Xcode and navigate to "File" -> "New" -> "Target"

[image]

- choose Notification Service Extension from the available options.

[image]

**Step 3**

A new class named "NotificationService" will be created, which should be extended from the "NetmeraNotificationServiceExtension" class. Your NotificationService class should look like the following,

```
class NotificationService : NetmeraNotificationServiceExtension {

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (_ contentToDeliver: UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        super.didReceive(request, withContentHandler: contentHandler)
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        super.serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire()
    }

}
```

Link the "Netmera.framework" to the Notification Service Extension. To do this, add your Notification Service Extension as a target to your Podfile by including the following line:

```
pod "Netmera/NotificationServiceExtension"
```

Update your Podfile to install the necessary dependencies and perform the linking process.

And for more to send carousel, slider notification you can review [here](https://user.netmera.com/developer-guide/push-notifications/ios-push/carousel-slider-and-thumbnail-push).

Answer (score -2):

Implement your notification's custom view using a UIViewController that conforms to UNNotificationContentExtension.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension