# How to provide Rich NotificationService(including image icon) to user?

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, rich-notifications

Recently I am working on a project and it has a requirement to embed rich notification. So I am taking service from firebase. Initially I have tried from these sites. and there are some hobby projects in youtube where they send notification from local machine.

https://www.avanderlee.com/ios-10/rich-notifications-ios-10/

[UNNotificationAttachment with UIImage or Remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103095/unnotificationattachment-with-uiimage-or-remote-url)

[How to implement rich notifications in ios 10 with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713145/how-to-implement-rich-notifications-in-ios-10-with-firebase)

[How to send Image with firebase Push Notification using swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266508/how-to-send-image-with-firebase-push-notification-using-swift-3)

But almost 16 hours I spent on it. It gave me 0 output because Title,sub-title came from firebase finely but there is no sign of image icon.

Please suggest me any approach or good video or something.

Comment: You need to create NotificationService Extension. Download attachment image in the extension class and Mutate the notification content.

Comment: Yes I did and I also added mutable-content/mutable_content for that but no sign of developing.

Comment: Are you running your app target or extension target ?

Comment: I am running in app target

Comment: Run extension target and select your app in the prompted list. And use breakpoint in extension class to check whether it is being executed or not.

Comment: I checked. Extension is not being called.

Comment: Have you configured your plist for the category name which you are sending from server ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to configure category name in plist which I am sending from server. What I will add/configure?

Comment: Add these lines in project's plist 

 <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
 <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
 <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>

Comment: See my answer for detail

Answer (score 0):

Your App target's plist should contain following lines

```
<key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key> 
<string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string> 
<key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key> 
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).NotificationService</string>
```

And Your extension's plist should look like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>RemotePushExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>XPC!</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.12</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.usernotifications.service</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>NotificationService</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Want to access your photo album to save image</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you say that what extra lines added in NotificationServiceExtension plist?