# Icon for push notification?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I am working on a chat app that receive push notification. I want to provide images/icon that will be used by iOS to display in push notification , where can I specify that in Xcode?

Comment: You cannot AFAIK. It will use the icon of your app. You can read more here : https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/features/notifications/

Comment: Sure you can, by using Images.xcassets. 
Just insert the image you want to the field "iPhone Notification" / "iPad Notification"

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification

Comment: @Losiowaty since iOS 10, you **can**. Just see the link Milander has shared...

Comment: there is also a very very good WWDC video related. See from [this moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/?time=444)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display image in ios push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification)

Answer (score 0):

To Accomplish this firstly you need to goto your Info.Plist file and add some properties in Icon-File that is

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleAlternateIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>first_icon</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
                <array>
                    <string>first_icon.png</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
            <key>second_icon</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
                <array>
                    <string>second_icon.png</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string></string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>UINewsstandIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string></string>
            </array>
            <key>UINewsstandBindingType</key>
            <string>UINewsstandBindingTypeMagazine</string>
            <key>UINewsstandBindingEdge</key>
            <string>UINewsstandBindingEdgeLeft</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Now you need to configure settings in your `AppDelegate` file

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

      dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSDictionary *notificationData = [[PushNotificationManager pushManager] getCustomPushDataAsNSDict:userInfo];
        NSString * notiIcon = [notificationData objectForKey:@"newIcon"];
        if([notiIcon isEqualToString:@"nil"])
          notiIcon = nil;

        NSLog(@"icon is: %@", notiIcon);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setAlternateIconName:notiIcon completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
          NSLog(@"Set icon error = %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }];
      });
```

now from any dashboard you send the notification to the app goto that and there would be and option named `Action` or something like `send Custom data` send a `key-value` pair in code we are using key 'newIcon' so send it like that

```
{"newIcon":"first_icon"}
```

now when you'll send the notification with iconName that will appear.

This will Work..

Comment: @Aashish Nagar I have changed my answer my previous answer was removed because of some copy right issues check this one now