# Apple Push Notification payload with image

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

[image]

I received push notification from an x app with image at right bottom (circled)

Need to show same sort of image in my app. What is apns payload structure for this. Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display image in ios push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification)

Answer (score -4):

For Remote Notification, set `mutable-content : 1` and `category : newCategory`. Note that the category value is set to "newCategory" which matches what you previously added to UNUserNotificationCenter and UNNotificationContentExtensions plist.

Example:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
        "title" : "title",
        "body" : "Your message Here"
        },
        "mutable-content" : "1",
        "category" : "newCategory"
    },
    "otherCustomURL" : "http://www.xxx.jpg"
 }
```

For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066583/742298