# FCM Push Notification "content" entry

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM to publish push notifications to my users, which is working great so far.

Currently I'm trying to implement a Notification Content Extension to deliver customized push notification and previews, which is working great with local notifications, following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066583/3191334).
As far I know, I have to set the `category` entry and my notification category identifier in the push notification, in order to tell iOS, which notification UI it is supposed to use.

The problem is, when I send the following message to FCM, with the category entry set, FCM erases the entry or changes it to `gcm.notification.category`, depending where I place the category entry (`aps` / `data`, etc.)

This way iOS never shows my custom UI / extension. Unfortunately I was not able to find any help in the [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

Send (POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send):

```
{ 
    "notification": {
        "title": "Good Morning",
        "body": "Wake up Jack!",
        "badge" : 1,
        "sound" : "horn.aiff",
        "category" : "Cheers"     <-- Is going to be deleted / changed
    },

    "data" : {
        "time" : "2018-01-19 23:00:00",
        ...
    },

    "mutable_content" : true,

    "priority" : "high",
    "registration_ids" : [
      "abcdefg123456"
    ]
}
```

Received:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "Wake up Jack!";
            title = "Good Morning";
        };
        badge = 1;
        "mutable-content" = 1;
    };

    "gcm.message_id" = "0:1516392279506894%dc84760ddc84760d";
    "gcm.notification.category" = "Cheers";    <-- not working 
}
```

Comment: Hi. Could you also post the *actual payload* you send with FCM? The one that isn't  translated to APNs payload yet.

Comment: Hi Al, thanks for your response and the hint, I copied the wrong JSON - it's up to date now :-)

Comment: Hmm. The `category` counterpart of the APNS payload for the FCM is `click_action` (as per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)). Have you tried it out?\

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much! - Feel free to post an answer and I'm happy to accept it! Have a great day!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `category` APNS parameter FCM counterpart is [`click_action`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref).

When adding in a custom parameter (using the `data` message payload), it is handled differently for iOS and is often included outside of the `aps` payload (like in the sample you provided).

Comment: Are we able to send schedule notifications like every day at a specific time using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send? (not from firebase console)