# FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION WITH IMAGE:- how to display tile, description and image in fcm push notification in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

how to display tile, description and image in fcm push notification in ios swift.

I extend NotificationViewController and NotificationService but NotificationService never calls.

Here is notification payload in the foreground.

For Good Suggestion. Thank in advance

PayLoad

{
  "alert": {
    "body": "Message",
    "title": "appname"
  },
  "content-available": 1,
  "mutable-content": 1,
  "sound": 1
}

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066583/8385972)

Comment: yes already follow this demo but service never calls. "category" property does not display in a payload. How to I add it my payLoad?