# PHP-iOS push-notifications with image

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send a push notification with an image content from my web application to iOS App. I got the notification with all the text and body message which I have given. But the given image is not displayed in the notification.

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$token = "*******************";
$title = "Title";
$body = "This is Test Notification";
$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $body, 'subtitle'=>'Sub title', 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1', 'category' => 'CustomSamplePush', 'mutable-content'=>'1','urlImageString'=>'imageurl');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');

$fields = json_encode($arrayToSend);
echo $fields;
    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "***********",
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'authKey: keyhere',
            'authKeyId:****',
            'teamId: ****',
            'bundleId: *****',
            'endpoint: https://api.development.push.apple.com'
        );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo $result;
    curl_close ( $ch );
```

Comment: May be this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification

Answer (score 0):

For showing Media content like Images, Audio and Videos you need to add the NotificationServiceExtension in your iOS App. For NotificationServiceExtension in iOS app to be executed you need to send mutable-content value as 1, which looks fine in the payload you mentioned.
In NotificationServiceExtension you will get around 10 seconds to download the image from the URL you are sending in the notification payload. Once the image is downloaded then you need to save the image in the FileManager. After that, you initialize UNNotificationAttachment with the file image URL and pass it to completion handler. PFA code below

```
import UserNotifications
```

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

```
var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here...
        var urlString:String? = nil
        if let urlImageString = request.content.userInfo["urlImageString"] as? String {
            urlString = urlImageString
        }

        if urlString != nil, let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString!) {
            print("fileUrl: \(fileUrl)")

            guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: fileUrl) else {
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                return
            }
            guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: "image.jpg", data: imageData, options: nil) else {
                print("error in UNNotificationAttachment.saveImageToDisk()")
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                return
            }

            bestAttemptContent.attachments = [ attachment ]
        }

        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}

override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

}

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
extension UNNotificationAttachment {

```
static func saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: String, data: NSData, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let folderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    let folderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)

    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        let fileURL = folderURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
        let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: fileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
        return attachment
    } catch let error {
        print("error \(error)")
    }

    return nil
}
```

}