# Push notification with Engage Digital (formerly Dimelo) didReceiveRemoteNotification never called

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications, push

I send notification I receive it on the phone no problem;

Now I want to customise image titre ...

the problem is this function on delegate was never called `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

On appDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
            // Dimelo: Push Notif and Badge
    dimelo?.updateAppBadgeNumber = true
    dimelo?.developmentAPNS = true
    dimelo?.initialize(withApiSecret: BuildConfig.GetInstance().getDimeloApiSecret(), domainName: BuildConfig.GetInstance().getDimeloDomainName(), delegate: self)



     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Register the device token.
    Dimelo.sharedInstance().deviceToken = deviceToken
}

func dimeloDidBeginNetworkActivity(_ dimelo: Dimelo?) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func dimeloDidEndNetworkActivity(_ dimelo: Dimelo?) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    dimelo?.consumeReceivedRemoteNotification(userInfo)
}
```

I already activate remote notification on baclground mode

but the function `didReceiveRemoteNotification` was never called :(

I'm integrating this RingCentral Engage Digital / Dimelo library:

https://github.com/ringcentral/engage-digital-messaging-ios/issues

Comment: maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this demo app using the Dimelo iOS SDK: https://github.com/tylerlong/GrandTravel-iOS/blob/master/GrandTravel/AppDelegate.swift
Could you please check my code and figure out the differences?

I suggest you to print logs for both `handleActionWithIdentifier` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

If it still doesn't work, please send email to devsupport@ringcentral.com and we will investigate.