# Sending an Image in iOS Push-Notifications through Firebase Cloud Messaging Console

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I am sending push-notifications to my iOS app users through Firebase Cloud Messaging Console. After I input the image URL, the image is displayed on the preview. But, after I publish the notification, I am not able to see the Image in the push-notification. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue? Appreciate your help[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to display image in ios push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839171/how-to-display-image-in-ios-push-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement Notification Service Extension as it shown where: https://docs.leanplum.com/docs/adding-images-to-push-notifications#ios-setup

Comment: QQ. What is leanplum? Is it about iOS documentation or some 3rd party tool?

Comment: It is just pointing to tutorial how to implemented Notification Service Extension.